# Alamofire JSON request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

How can I read and parse a GET response as JSON?
I can read it but I can't parse JSON in swift, actually I don't know what is type `JSON` below:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=129caade072f51df051a20980f3cc86d&tags=landscape&per_page=1&page=1&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_sig=d02d3a7464d69a328e598e02dfc595af")
         .responseJSON { (_, _, JSON, _) in
                  println(JSON)

         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use on of the following JSON deserialization libraries https://github.com/matteocrippa/awesome-swift#json